# How to put delat in execution of .exe file created from visual studio project execution

Tags: visual-c++, exe

I created p1.exe by execution project p1 and d1.dll by execution project d1

p1.exe using the d1.dll file. When I double click p1.exe it shows output but appear for a moment and disappear.

Any idea how to see exe file persistantly?

Comment: Out put would be show in that manner only!